# Dispose of objects in user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a usercontrol that uses a DataSet objects. I would like to implement the IDisposable interface, however the usercontrol's designer class already has the following method:

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

How can I correctly dispose of my DataSet object?

Comment: You can move the designer generated `Dispose` method to your code and modify it.

Comment: Moving it is fine and doesn't break anything.  As clearly visible from the #region that warns what part you should not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call that once the control is disposed. Just subscribe to the [`Disposed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.disposed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of the control and dispose your own classes inside.

Comment: Did that. The event is never raised when I close the form where the usercontrol resides.

Comment: How did you open the form? `ShowDialog` maybe? It means your form didn't dispose. MEMORY LEAKING ALERT!

Comment: Yes with ShowDialog. How to I dispose of a form correctly then? I'm using the control's OnHandleDestroyed event to dispose of objects and it's working.

Comment: Set a using around the form constructor in your calling code.

Comment: Read here on the need for it: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/1004be6c-c559-4e57-a6fd-c189f01e3cd3/showdialog-dispose-memory-leak

Answer (score 2):

overriden `Dispose` method is not a part of `Component Designer generated code`

so you can modify it

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        if (components != null)
            components.Dispose();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Dispose DataSet Here");
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to safely handle disposing the Dataset object, is putting it in a `using` clause:

```
using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
{
        // Put code that adds stuff to DataSet here.
        // ... The DataSet will be cleaned up outside the block.
}
```

This way you don't have to manually dispose the DataSet object afterwards. It will be disposed when leaving the `using` block.

[Using (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

Comment: Indeed. This works only when the dataset is shortly lived. If it is kept in memory over methods, this won't work.

Comment: @PatrickHofman You are right, this isn't the best solution when dealing with datasets that should be kept longer in memory. However it could be a helpful solution.